# PHP/SQL math adding issue

Tags: php, sql, math

So I have this code...

```
$remaining = $remaining + $row['total'];
```

and this is in a foreach loop..

```
foreach($clientArrayInvoice as $key => $row)
```

and its doing is going through each record and adding on the totals into this `$remaining` variable, some of the records totals are positive numbers and some are negative numbers, its seems to work fine, but I need to display the `$remaining` variable after its finsihed with a record and I got this as one of the results...

```
-2.84217094304E-14
```

This came out of no where, all the math adds up that that should be `0` and not `-2.84217094304E-14`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the query where the totals are coming from

```
select i.invoiceid as transactionid, i.date, i.total, 
i.total - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p where p.invoice = i.invoiceid) as remainingbalance,
'invoice' as transaction_type
        from invoice i inner join client c
        on i.client = c.clientid
        where i.isdeleted = 0 and i.client = " . $clientId . "
        union
select p.paymentid as transactionid, p.date,(0 - p.amount) as total, p.invoice, 'payment' as transaction_type
        from payment p inner join invoice i
        on i.invoiceid = p.invoice
        inner join paymenttype
        on paymenttype.paymenttypeid = p.paymenttypeid
        inner join client c
        on c.clientid = i.client
        where c.clientid = " . $clientId . "
        and i.isdeleted = 0
        order by date
```

Thanks and I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Floating point numbers work this way.  They aren't exact.

Comment: Yes - don't use floating point numbers to represent currency values.  Bad choice.

Comment: `$remaining = (intval)$remaining;` this must help

Comment: `intval($remaining)` works but I do need the decimals :(

Comment: Then you're stuck.  10^-14 will be a fact of life.  Round it when you're rendering and make yourself feel better.

Comment: You do realize that `-2.84217094304E-14` equals `0.00000000000000284...`?

Answer (score 0):

don't store money as floats - e.g. store it as integers (in cents + present the amounts as `cents / 100`)

or whatever you find usefull from https://www.google.com/search?q=money+datatypes